# Is "dom model" a part of html or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, model, protocols

I can use "document.X" in javascript to visit a html page, and all its tags. Is this ability defined by html protocol or EMCA protocol? Or it's a javascript implementation choice, that every browser's DOM model could be a bit different?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Different parts and aspects of that are defined in different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just a web api.
any programming language can choose to implement access to that api.
obviously every programming language can choose to implement it differently

[see the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)

> Although the DOM is often accessed using JavaScript, it is not a part
>   of the JavaScript language. It can also be accessed by other languages